# Should I bind my buffers to GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER when uploading data?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I don't have access to direct buffer access, so I need to bind my buffers to upload data to them.  Normally I bound them to the target they're used for, but I recently learned that `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` cannot legally be bound outside of a Vertex Array Object definition, and must be bound elsewhere.

I'm thinking I should try binding all my buffers to a different target for consistency, when uploading.  Would `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` be a good buffer for this purpose?  Or should I only do this for `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`?

Comment: Where did you get this info?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget - https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification (ctrl+f for "VAO object 0")

Comment: Related: [Binding to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER with no VAO bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391921/binding-to-gl-element-array-buffer-with-no-vao-bound)